# Test app in release mode

Tags: java, android

How do I test an app while in release mode? I tried `ant release test`, but it gave this error

```
test:
 [echo] Running tests ...
 [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
 [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.kizbit.speedyreader.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
 [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
 [exec] android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.kizbit.speedyreader.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

I already copied the keystore to the test project.

I want to test while in release mode, because it saves a lot of state. If I re-install in debug mode, then I have to uninstall and re-install it, and that deletes all the state.

Comment: Can't you just keep it in debug mode? Is there any reason to need release mode on your own device?

Comment: @Doomsknight I guess I like to be certain what I'm seeing is the same as users... just paranoid. No real reason. I just had a lot of saved data and didn't want to lose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found a way. Be sure to check the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml for the test package and the path to your test classes. For some reason, the package name in the manifest was com....tests, while the classes were not in /tests directory. I don't know how it ever worked, but it used to work for normal debug.

To get it to test in release mode, you have to use `ant release install test`.  I forgot the install. Also, `test` will always build the debug version of your app, so you have to manually go to the real app project directory, and run `ant release install`, which will install the release version. Then, go to the test project directory and run `ant release install test`. This will give an error

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]
```

when it tries to install the actual app, because it is already installed with the release key. You can ignore this. Also, you have to remove the debug version of the test project with `adb uninstall com........tests` to make sure it doesn't give this error when you try to install the release version of the test.

Also, you must copy the release.keystore file from the real project directory into the test project directory, and if you have your keys saved in ant.properties, you have to copy these entries into the test ant.properties also

```
key.store=release.keystore
key.alias=mykey
key.store.password=password
key.alias.password=password
```

Then it will test with the release version!

Just remember that since it doesn't install the actual app, you have to re-compile and re-install the release version manually from the app directory if you are changing things. Maybe there is a way to automatically build & install the release version by modifying the build.xml, but I haven't checked into that yet.

Comment: Fair enough :). +1 for finding a way to do it.

Comment: Ended up just keeping debug version on phone and deleting/re-creating the data I wanted to save. Adding and fixing unit tests are a lot easier that way.

Comment: I tried this approach, but it will fail, if you use proguard and in your test project you use methods that have been optimized away by proguard